# Householder's QR?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

We have the following geometrical intuition behind Householder's QR factorisation:
[image]

where we want to reflect a vector $\mathbf{a}$ over the dotted mirror line to end up on the x-axis. We do that by defining the reflection matrix $\mathbf{Q}_1 = \mathbf{I}-2\mathbf{\hat{y}}\mathbf{\hat{y}}^T$. But why can't/don't we just subtract $\mathbf{y}$ directly from $\mathbf{a}$? Then the matrix would be $\mathbf{Q}_1 = \mathbf{I}-\mathbf{y}$? I mean then the input vector $\mathbf{a}$ would still be reflected onto the x-axis(specifically, $||a||_2 \mathbf{e}_1$), right?

Comment: $I$ is a matrix and $y$ is a vector.  You can't compute $I-y$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Ah okay. But can't you in some other way create a matrix that directly subtracts $\mathbf{y}$? My main question is about why you don't subtract it directly, not necessarily how you would make $\mathbf{Q}_1$ :)

Comment: Another key point here is that you want the matrix $Q_{1}$ to be an orthogonal matrix.  You'll be using $Q_{1}$ in other places where this orthogonality is required.